# PHP Ajax, how to update a number dynamically?

Tags: ajax

In my PHP application, I have a web page that says "New Leads: 0" The "0" is the result of a SQL statement.

My goal is to add Ajax code so the "0" updates dynamically, without having to refresh the page.  When the number of rows increases in the database, I want the "New Leads: 0" to automatically increase.

My question is can you point me in the right direction of how I can code this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a page that outputs the number, put the number into a `<span id="the_number">` then call the [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) on that `span` to fetch that page. Use the `window.setInterval()` function to make it periodically.